# Common typing area for mobile browsers

Tags: jquery, html

I have several stack of input boxes within overflowed div.
When the user focus on one of input box the native keyboard slides out and you cant see where or what you are typing.

So my solution was to create a common typing area. I found one answer that is close and tweaked it but I can't get it to post back to input box. Please help, Thanks in advance!

https://jsfiddle.net/JCprog/p797v44b/14/

```
$('.jml').on('focus', function(){
$('#divChoices').show()
$('#ch1').focus()
thefield = $(this).prev()
$('.btnselect').on('click', function(){
    theselected = $(this).prev()
    thefield.val( $('#ch1').val() )
    $('#divChoices').hide()
})
```

})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never declare a handler inside another one:

```
$('.btnselect').on('click', function(){
```

In this way you add a new handler every time a **jml** field gets focus.

I'd suggest to add a class to the focused element and use that class after when closing the div:

```js
$('.jml').on('focus', function(e){
    $('#divChoices').show();
    $('#ch1').val(this.value).focus();
    //
    // add class to current input field
    //
    $(this).addClass('active');
})

$('.btnselect').on('click', function(e) {
    //
    // use the class to select the input field and remove it
    //
    $('.jml.active').val( $('#ch1').val()).removeClass('active');
    $('#divChoices').hide();
})
```

```css
#divChoices {
    border: none;
    position: fixed;
    text-align:center;
    top: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
}
#divChoices input[type="text"]{
    height:25%;
    width:57%

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="divform">

    <input class="jml" size="75" type="text"><br>
    <input class="jml" size="75" type="text"><br>
    <input class="jml" size="75" type="text"><br>
    <input class="jml" size="75" type="text"><br>
    <input class="jml" size="75" type="text"><br>
    <input class="jml" size="75" type="text"><br>
    <input class="jml" size="75" type="text"><br>
    <input class="jml" size="75" type="text"><br>
    <input class="jml" size="75" type="text"><br>
    <input class="jml" size="75" type="text"><br>
    <input class="jml" size="75" type="text"><br>
</div>

<div id="divChoices">
    <input type="text" id="ch1" name="ch1"><br>
    <button id="btnsel1" class="btnselect">Done</button>
</div>
```